# Adjustment renderValueBox function in R

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I created a function to calculate predicted values ​​according to 3 variables.

However I am unable to adjust the `renderValueBox` function to make the calculation.

The code is here (`write in rmarkdown`):

````
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill
    theme: cosmo
---

```{r}
library(tidyverse)

df_2 <- data.frame(
  m = seq(from = .05, to = .95, by = .05), 
  d = seq(from = .04, to = .94, by = .05), 
  q = c(1:18, 2000)
)

desconto <- function(mc, desc, qtde) {
  ((((mc) / (mc - desc)) - 1) * qtde + qtde)
}

price <- desconto(
  mc = df_2$m, 
  desc = df_2$d, 
  qtde = df_2$q
)
```

```{r}
library(shiny)
library(flexdashboard)
```
```

Predict values
=================================
Sidebar{.sidebar data-width=300}
---------------------------------

```{r}
# Widgets
sliderInput(
  inputId = 'm', label = 'mc', 
  value = mean(round(x = df_2$m, digits = 0)) * 100, 
  min = min(round(x = df_2$m, digits = 0)) * 100, 
  max = max(round(x = df_2$m, digits = 0)) * 100
)

sliderInput(
  inputId = 'd', label = 'dc', 
  value = mean(round(x = df_2$d, digits = 0)) * 100, 
  min = min(round(x = df_2$d, digits = 0)) * 100, 
  max = max(round(x = df_2$d, digits = 0)) * 100
)

numericInput(
  inputId = 'q', label = 'qtde', 
  value = mean(round(x = df_2$q, digits = 0)), 
  min = min(round(x = df_2$q, digits = 0)), 
  max = max(round(x = df_2$q, digits = 0))
)
```

```{r}
# Reactive object
reac_1 <- reactive({
  tibble(
    m = input$m, 
    d = input$d, 
    q = input$q
  )
})

# Reactive output
pred_4 <- reactive({
  x = reac_1()$price
})
```

Calculator{}
----------------------
```{r}
renderValueBox(
  valueBox(
    value = pred_4()
  )
)
```
````

For example, for `mc = 50`, `dc = 20` and `qtde = 1500` the expected result would be `2500`.

- The problem is in the function `renderValueBox`

Thank's a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the line `reac_1()$price`. Look at how you define `reac_1`, there is no `price` column. (You also don't ever use the `price` object that you define in the first code chunk, I'd delete it for clarity)

One solution modifies `pred_4` like this:

```
pred_4 <- reactive({
  temp <- reac_1()
  desconto(
  mc = temp$m,
  desc = temp$d,
  qtde = temp$q
)
})
```